# Continuing with prior formatting after pasting into Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

Lets say I start with the default font in Microsoft Word. Then I copy and paste some text from elsewhere (say a webpage). When I start typing after that, the font is whatever font the copied text had, and not the default font, I started with.

Is there a quick way to switch to the default font? I usually achieve this by copying something typed in the original font, typing after that, and deleting the text I copied.

Comment: Do you want the copied text to have the font it brought it, or for it also to use the font in use where it was pasted?

Comment: You can also paste only the text, not the formatting.  It's under Paste->Special or similar (depending on which version you're using).  This preserves your current font/color/size when pasting.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. I do not want to change the formatting of the copied text ( I want it to look the same way it looked on , say a webpage). When I open a blank Microsoft Word 2013 document, the font is Calibri(Body) 11. Let's say I copy from a webpage and it's font is Ariel, 10, blue, and I want to keep this formatting. When I type something after that I want the font to be Calibri(Body) 11, black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Word versions with the Ribbon, the "Paste" button on the toolbar has a pulldown under it. This offers four options. You want the one at the extreme right, which pastes the text only.

In the same pulldown you'll find "set default paste". Click  that, scroll down to the "cut, copy, and paste" section, and you can set the default behavior.

Also, if you forget and just do a regular Paste, a little "Ctrl" pulldown menu appears beside the pasted material. Click the down-arrow and you have the same four options available. This lets you easily fix these. No need to copy other stuff around.

Comment: And... If you want to preserve the style of the copied text, but not have your text after that adopt that style: Just type one letter or even a space extra, and do your paste from the other material before that. e.g. if you were typing word1 word2 and you wanted to paste between the two, just type word1 and hit space twice; do your paste between the two spaces; hit the End key and keep going. You probably want those spaces anyway.

Comment: OK Didnt think of that!

Answer (score 0):

Paste the content using Keep Source Formatting option as usual and then to go back to the original formatting for the text after it click the Body style from the Quick Style pane.