# Default font for current document in Microsoft Word changes after pasting text

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I know how to set the default font in Microsoft Word. I find that if I create a new document and paste from a different document source which uses a different font, the new document will now ignore my default font. With commands like "clear formatting" or Ctrl+Shift+N ("apply the Normal style"), highlighted text will be set to the foreign imported font - even after I have highlighted all text in the document and changed it to my default. Any idea how to change / fix this? I would expect any new document to truly keep my default font and not be influenced by pasted text.

I know I could paste with "Paste Special" and use "unformatted text" option. However, sometimes I want other formatting - e.g. tables.

FYI, I'm on Word 2003, but I doubt this matters.

**UPDATE**
I have tried all the Paste Special options, but only unformatted text clears the font.

So far, the only way I have cleared the font from the document, is to copy it to a Wordpad document and then copy it back to Word. I lost page formatting and headers / footers, but at least kept the tables intact.

**UPDATE 2**
Looks like another good answer in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/838377/continuing-with-prior-formatting-after-pasting-into-microsoft-word?rq=1). Except it looks to also be for a more recent version of Word. This is actually the first time in all these years that there is a feature not in the 2003 version that may be worth something. But not enough of a reason to change.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to try the 'Merge Formatting' option. This will clear the font but leave things like tables, bold, underline, and relative font sizes (I believe).

**Original**
[image]

**Merged**
[image]

Comment: Sounds like the solution, except I can't test it in Word 2003. Looks like a feature that came with 2010. Thanks for the info.